# How to develope my own language pack for sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have some experience to administrating sharepoint 2010 and developing webparts but now I'm working on sharepoint 2013.i want to develop my own language pack for this,but i don't know from where i should start.I didn't find any tutorial for this.

any help really appreciate.

best regards.

Comment: You want to override some, but not all, of the standard text in the UI? Why would you want to do that business-wise?

Comment: You can't create your own language pack. Only way to override texts on out-of-the-box controls is with javascript / replacing them with custom controls.

Comment: Thanks Ronnie,no I don't want to change all the text, I just made a PWA and I want to change its language.